# Adjusting spacing between :before pseudoelement image and text

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I am trying to adjust an image which sits just before the text. But the problem is that the image width takes some space to the right because of the alphabet style A.

I have created a demo:

```css
h1:before{
    content: url('http://s9.postimg.org/bg93v6bjf/image.png');
}
```

```html
<h1>pple</h1>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/wott37vy/

How can I reduce the space between A and p so that even I resize the browser it stays at the same place?

Any help is highly welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean this ? http://jsfiddle.net/wott37vy/1/ but what about resizing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One clean way to solve this would be to set the pseudoelement's display to `inline-block`, and give it a defined width.

Here is a **Live Demo**:

```css
h1:before{
    display: inline-block;
    content: url('http://s9.postimg.org/bg93v6bjf/image.png');
    width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<h1>pple</h1>
```

JSFiddle Version: http://jsfiddle.net/wott37vy/3/

Comment: Brilliant...you are a star....Thank you so much for your help. I was pulling my hair out for last one hour. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use negative `margin` values to [take away space](http://jsfiddle.net/wott37vy/4/).

```css
h1:before{
    content: url('http://s9.postimg.org/bg93v6bjf/image.png');
}

h1 span {
    margin-left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>pple</span></h1>
```

Comment: Thanks mate...I won't be able to use margin due to some reason....I have to use display inline block. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap your logo in a div:

```
<div><h1>pple</h1></div>
```

And then give that `div` a fixed width so that it does not resize by itself:

```
div {
    width: 180px;
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to be working when I try it. Could you provide a live demo of what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the prettiest solution but you can add a negative margin to the right side of your image to bring the text closer like so,

```
h1:before {
    content: url('http://s9.postimg.org/bg93v6bjf/image.png');
    margin:0 -20px 0 0;
    padding:0;
}
```